# Is it possible to shift the Cesium globe to the right of center?

Tags: cesiumjs

Is it possible to shift the globe to the left or right of center? I would like to display the starfield below a transparent navigation sidebar, and shift-right the globe a distance equal to the width of the sidebar.

I can't find any examples of this, and I don't see reference to existing methods in Cesium. I experimented with making the Cesium div larger than its container and using positioning to make the globe appear to be shift to the right, but this showed blurring of the starfield due to the enlargement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, from the UI this is done by holding the SHIFT key and dragging, but in code it can be done with the [lookLeft](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Camera.html#lookLeft) and [lookRight](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Camera.html#lookRight) methods on the camera.

For example:

```
viewer.camera.lookLeft(Cesium.Math.toRadians(20));
```

Here's a more complete example, press "Run Code Snippet" at the bottom of this:

```js
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
    // All these construction options are just to avoid Stack Snippet error messages.
    navigationInstructionsInitiallyVisible: false, animation: false, timeline: false,
    imageryProvider : Cesium.createTileMapServiceImageryProvider({
        url : Cesium.buildModuleUrl('Assets/Textures/NaturalEarthII')
    }),
    baseLayerPicker : false,
    geocoder : false,
    infoBox : false
});

// This changes where the Earth is seen by the camera.
viewer.camera.lookLeft(Cesium.Math.toRadians(20));
```

```css
html, body, #cesiumContainer {
    width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cesiumjs.org/releases/1.55/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css" 
      rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cesiumjs.org/releases/1.55/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js">
</script>
<div id="cesiumContainer"></div>
```

Comment: this answer explains how to shift camera, not how to shift globe... Is it possible to shift the globe center?

Comment: Not sure I understand.  The Earth is where it is in space, Cesium can't offer an option to put it elsewhere without messing up a lot of calculations.  Rotating the camera is how one makes the globe appear in a different place on screen.  The center of rotation typically stays with the Earth in Cesium.  And note that "camera.lookLeft" doesn't actually move the camera's position, it rotates it in place.

Comment: I would like to move the center of the reference system (i.e. Earth center by default) to Sun center position, so I could use ephemeris of spacecrafts, given w.r.t Sun, directly in Cesium without any weird coordinate conversion; i also would like to simulte single planets other than Earth, but in their actual position w.r.t Sun.

Comment: That's a great question, but totally separate from this one.  Unfortunately Cesium doesn't have the robust support for this that STK has.  Still, it may be worth asking this as a separate Stack Overflow question, or on the Cesium forums, to see if anyone has ideas.  But I think for a heliocentric system visualization you'll probably need STK.

Comment: STK is not an option for me. I started experimenting with a "Cesium solar system": https://jsfiddle.net/spacexplorer2020/2w1Lcy43/37/